# Word cloud using jQcloud won't appear

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, word-cloud

I'm trying to create a word cloud for my json. I've been referring to this page on how to do word cloud using jQcloud http://mistic100.github.io/jQCloud/demo.html

At first there wasn't any error but now there is an error on the console saying that it cannot create property 'weight' on string '{text: "mark", weight: 8}'. I'm still a newbie. It would be great if somebody can point out the mistake. The coding is on my process.php file.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $data = $_POST["d2"];
    $obj = json_decode($data, TRUE);

    $item = array();
    foreach($obj as $key => $value) 
    {
        $item[] = '{text: "'.$key.'", weight: '.$value.'}';

        $sql = "SELECT word FROM test WHERE word = '$key'";
        $r = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
        $row0 = mysql_num_rows($r);

        if($row0 != 0)
        {
            $found = "UPDATE test SET weight = $value WHERE word = '$key'";
            mysql_query($found) or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
        }
    }
    echo print_r($item);
}?>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqcloud.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqcloud-1.0.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var varNameSpace = <?php echo json_encode($item); ?>;
varNameSpace = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(varNameSpace));
alert(varNameSpace);
$(function() {
    $("#d").jQCloud(varNameSpace);
  });

</head>
<body>
<div id="d" style="width: 550px; height: 350px; border: 1px solid #ccc;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I alert the **varNameSpace**, the example output will be like this:

```
{text: "mark", weight: 8},
{text: "zuckerberg", weight: 4},
{text: "money", weight: 2},
{text: "man", weight: 2},
{text: "and", weight: 7},
{text: "having", weight: 1},
{text: "apart", weight: 8},
{text: "rich", weight: 2},
{text: "of", weight: 3},
{text: "world", weight: 2},
{text: "less", weight: 1}
```

this is the example output of **echo json_encode($item)** on the console:

```
["{text: \"mark\", size: 8}",
"{text: \"apart\", size: 8}",
"{text: \"and\", size: 7}",
"{text: \"zuckerberg\", size: 4}" ...and many more];
```

when I echo the **$item** using **print_r**, this is the example output:

```
Array ( [0] => {text: "mark", size: 8} [1] 
=> {text: "apart", weight: 8} [2] 
=> {text: "and", weight: 7} [3] 
=> {text: "zuckerberg", size: 4} ...and many more ) 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting a plain JSON-formatted string to your variable. Wrap it with `JSON.parse()` to convert it to an object:

```js
var varNameSpace = <?php echo json_encode($item); ?>;
varNameSpace = JSON.parse(varNameSpace);
```

Comment: I've edited my code. I did what you asked me to do and there was an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse(<anonymous>). I solved it by adding JSON.stringify but now another error occured. It says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'weight' on string '{text: "mark", weight: 8}'.

Comment: what is inside your `$item` php variable?

Comment: At first I got a json data from js file, I did a counter for number of words and I got something like this:

{
  "mark": 8,
  "zuckerberg": 4,
...and many more..
}

then pass the json data to php file and loop through it to add the word **text** and **weight** and thus, the example result is like this on the console (this is inside the `$items` where I pass it to **var varNameSpace**):

["{text: \"mark\", weight: 8}",
"{text: \"zuckerberg\", weight: 4}",
"{text: \"man\", weight: 2},
and many more..."];